# Convert datatype to string (SML)

Tags: type-conversion, sml

I have a function that returns a `(char * int) list list`, like `[[(#"D", 3)], [(#"F", 7)]]`, and now I'm wondering if it's posssible to convert this to a string, so that I can use I/O and read it to another file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I assume you meant a value like `[[(#"D", 3)], [(#"F", 7)]]` (note the extra parens) since SML requires parentheses around tuple construction. OCaml uses a slightly different syntax, and allows just commas, like `a, b`, to construct tuples. I mention this because what follows is totally specific to Standard ML, and doesn't apply to OCaml, because I believe that in OCaml your best bet is an entirely different approach, which I don't know much about (macros, i.e. ocamlp4/5). So I assume that was just a typo and that you're interested in Standard ML.

Now, unfortunately there is no general `toString` function in Standard ML. Something like that would have to have some kind special support in the language and implementation, since it's not possible to write a function with the type `'a -> string`. You basically have to write your own `toString : t -> string` for each type `t`.

As you can imagine, this gets tedious fast. I've spent a little time researching the options (for this and other boilerplate functions like `compare : 't * 't -> order`) and there is one very interesting technique outlined in the paper "Generics for the working ML'er" (http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1292547) but it's pretty advanced and I could never actually get the code to compile (that said the paper is very interesting) The full generics library described in that paper is in the MLton lib repo (https://github.com/MLton/mltonlib/tree/master/com/ssh/generic/unstable). Maybe you'll have better luck?

Here's a slightly lighter weight approach that is less powerful but easier to understand, IMHO. I wrote this after reading that paper and struggling to get it to work. The idea is to write building blocks for `toString` functions (called `show` in this case) and compose them with other functions for your own types.

```
structure Show =
   struct
      (* Show.t is the type of toString functions *)
      type 'a t = 'a -> string

      val int: int t = Int.toString

      val char: char t = Char.toString

      val list: 'a t -> 'a list t =
       fn show => fn xs => "[" ^ concat (ExtList.interleave (map show xs) ",") ^ "]"

      val pair: 'a t * 'b t -> ('a * 'b) t =
       fn (showa,showb) => fn (a,b) => "(" ^ showa a ^ "," ^ showb b ^ ")"

      (* ... *)
   end
```

Since your type doesn't actually have any user defined datatypes, it's very easy to write the `toString` function using this structure:

```
local
   open Show
in
   val show : (char * int) list list -> string = list (list (pair (char, int)))
end

- show [[(#"D", 3)], [(#"F", 7)]] ;
val it = "[[(D,3)],[(F,7)]]" : string
```

What I like about this is that the composed functions read like the type turned inside out. It's a quite an elegant style, which I cannot take credit for as I took it from the generics paper linked above.

The rest of the code for `Show` (and a related module `Eq` for equality comparison) is here: https://github.com/spacemanaki/lib.sml

Comment: Great! Thank you! Just one question: exactly what does the `ExtList` structure do, and why is it needed in the `show`stucture?

Comment: `ExtList` is just some utility functions for manipulating lists: https://github.com/spacemanaki/lib.sml/blob/master/lib.sml#L3. The `Show` module uses `interleave` in `Show.list`.

Comment: Very clever design. It's a shame it still requires so much work compared to the equivalent in dynamically-typed languages, like Python's `__str__` and `__repr__` mechanisms.